# Problems with D3 in React on update data from useState

Tags: reactjs, svg, d3.js, bubble-chart

Im using react and have started play around with D3 for creating a Bubble Chart.
Our main ide is that we have a useState that is changing over time with data.
Three things can happen to data: New, Delete or Update. Update is a Value that is updated rest is the same. Value is used to calculate the size of the Bubble.
So I get this working but the issue is that every time we get new data everything is redrawn and I want an effect of them moving around and deleted one fly away and new ones transition in to position. I have now spent a couple of days going through guides, threads etc but nothing maps what I have going on.

So lets go through the process (a bit cut but main steps are there):

1. renderSVG (runs ones on load)

```
svg.current.innerHTML = '';
svg.current.style.overflow = "visible";
```

2. renderChart (runs on every load)

```
    const pack = d3.pack()
      .size([width * graph.zoom, width * graph.zoom])
      .padding(padding);
    const root = d3.hierarchy({ children: data })
      .sum(function (d) { return d.value; })
      .sort(function (a, b) { return b.value - a.value; })
    const dataPack = pack(root).leaves();
```

We use this code to create a packed circle

3. renderBubbles (runs only first time)

```
 const bubbleChart = d3.select(svg.current).append("g")
      .attr("class", "bubble-chart")

        var nodes = bubbleChart
      .selectAll(".node")
      .data(dataPack)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      })

 nodes.append("circle")
      .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
      .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d.data.color ? d.data.color : color(nodes.indexOf(d));
      })
      .style("z-index", 1)
      .attr("r", function (d) {
        return d.r - (d.r * .04);
      })
```

So if we hade no new data this would be hunky dory. Working like a charm. I can see the bubbles nicely (no transitions here for simpler code).

But now to the tricky part. How to update this!

I have a separate method called update that runs on all data updates.
It first does renderChart as first time to get the sorted dataPack.
But then everything I does will just make it enter all data as new and exit all data as old.

I have tried so many different routes here but my main issue is the first selection.
Things I tried:
Storing above nodes in useState to try to update that one

Tried data mapping on the useState

```
 const node = selection.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
```

Tried data mapping on the dataPack from renderCharts

```
 const node = selection.selectAll(".node")
      .data(dataPack)
```

Tried filtering selectAll. Tried selectAll("g"), selectAll("bubble-chart").
Tried merge in stead of data.

Cant say that everything failed. I have succeed doing update on radius size for example. But all in all its always all old data exit enter and all new data enter. Meaning everything is rendered.

So sorry for long post. My main idea is that I need to store some sort of a state in renderBubles. This since I need information from the html code to do match against. I then need to some type of a select with either data or merge to get an accurate state with new data enter, and old deleted on exit. Then I think I can manage update stuff etc.

Any ideas on where Im thinking wrong or what I should store to pick up?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use **initialDepth** props to prevent redrawing the tree. In my case, I have initial depth of 1 in state. The trick part here is to know how many nodes you will about to display. In our backend, I pulled user network with 5 children, so I add it up and set my initialDepth to 6. Hope this helps.

EDIT: You can access `__rd3t.depth` to get the depth using **renderCustomNodeElement** props.